# Code error when submitting search query

Tags: php

I'm getting error on this:

> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\tet\search_motifasni2.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\tet\search_motifasni2.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tet\search_motifasni2.php on line 32
>   doc with term:

Codes:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

        //retrieve search word, trim, remove duplicate
        $find = $_POST['find'];
        $find = ltrim($find);
        $find = rtrim($find);
        $find = split(" ",$find);//line 10
        $find = array_unique($find);
```

. . .

```
        if($val<>" " and strlen($val)>0)
        {
            $sql .=" Terms = '$val' or";//line 18
        }
    }
```

. . .

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM document";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);//line 32
```

Tried many ways but still getting the same result when searched a query.

Comment: for one thing it looks like you can replace split (a deprecated function) with explode.. about $val.. we can't see from the code you provided what value it should have..neither $sql or $query..

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `split` is deprecated: instead use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). (like this: `$find = explode(' ', $find);` which is basically the same)
Also, you use both `ltrim` *and* `rtrim`, I think you could just as well use [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), which does both.

The second error is thrown because the `$sql` variable you use is not yet defined on line 18, you can't concatenate a string to a variable that is not yet defined (actually you can, because php is very humble, but it's not nice)
It can be easily solved by putting `$sql = '';` before the `if` statement.

The last error means `mysql_num_rows` gets `false` as an argument, while it needs a mysql resource. `$result` is false, so `mysql_query` returns false, which it does when there's an error while executing the query, see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Does your table `document` exist?

Comment: Thanks, split and $sql are now solved. Yes, my table document is exist.

Comment: Replace `$result = mysql_query($query);` with `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and it should give you a more descriptive error. Descriptive stuff makes it easier for us to help you :)

Comment: Thanks @reanimation, found the cause of the problem but now I'm getting unrelated result.

Comment: I have edited the first post with my current problem that the codes is displaying all the documents inside my document table and I'm only expecting the result should be the documents that contain the terms I've searched for.

Answer (score 2):

> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tet\search_motifasni2.php on line 10

As said, split is depricated, use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead

> Notice: Undefined variable: sql in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tet\search_motifasni2.php on line 18

You haven't initialized the `$sql` variable, somewhere before this code you should initialize $sql as an empty string or something

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tet\search_motifasni2.php on line 32 doc with
>   term:

As said, the mysql_query result you are passing into the mysql_num_row is a boolean, you should add more relevant code to get to the bottom of this ...

EDIT: The result from `mysql_query($query)` is false, something is wrong with your query, does your mysql user have access to the database or tables?

Comment: Thanks! Now is solving problem the mysql_query result problem.

Comment: The result from `mysql_query($query)` is false, something is wrong with your query, does your mysql user have access to the database or tables?

Comment: I have edited the first post and provided the codes with mysql_query($query).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `$sql .= ...;`' you must define it by doing `$sql = '';` first. And use other function than split. Probably mysql_query fails and returns `false`,

Answer (score 0):

Split is indeed deprecated as of 5.3.0, just read:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

You are trying to add to the $sql variable by using the "." operand so you need to check whether $sql was previously declared

I believe your 3rd point has been answered previously here:

[MySQL query boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988425/mysql-query-boolean-given)